# How to encapsulating API response inside "data" keys and paginate them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, pagination, active-model-serializers, json-api

I am using active model serializers to serialize the users.

In my **Seller controller** I have,

```
def index
   seller = User.all.where(catagories: "seller")
   render json: seller, status: :ok,  status: :ok
end
```

`UserSerializer` class looks like this.

```
  attributes :id, :name, :email, :phone_number, :verified
  has_many :products
  has_one :address`
```

Output is also fair enough.

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Craig Crist",
            "email": "adena_kiehn@greenfelder.com",
            "phone_number": "876.862.8760 x0096",
            "verified": true,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Direct Performance Transmitter",
                    "price": 1000,
                    "warranty": false,
                    "discount": 50,
                    "description": "Vel doloribus distinctio nihil rerum libero. Reprehenderit ratione cumque porro nesciunt. Id recusandae aut vel voluptatem aperiam hic deleniti voluptas."
                }
            ],
            "address": {
                "id": 1,
                "latitude": 41.022921,
                "longitude": -118.064638782714,
                "street_name": "Beattystr.",
                "city": "Hermannport"
            }
        }
```

but I need that response to be encapsulated inside a key called `data`.

```
data : {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Craig Crist",
                "email": "adena_kiehn@greenfelder.com",
                "phone_number": "876.862.8760 x0096",
                "verified": true,
                "products": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Direct Performance Transmitter",
                        "price": 1000,
                        "warranty": false,
                        "discount": 50,
                        "description": "Vel doloribus distinctio nihil rerum libero. Reprehenderit ratione cumque porro nesciunt. Id recusandae aut vel voluptatem aperiam hic deleniti voluptas."
                    }
                ],
                "address": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "latitude": 41.022921,
                    "longitude": -118.064638782714,
                    "street_name": "Beattystr.",
                    "city": "Hermannport"
                }
            }
```

I can achieve that by wrapping the data with `data` key in a hash like below
   so my index method looks like this.

```
 def index
   seller = User.all.where(catagories: "seller")
   render json:  { data: { user: seller } },  status: :ok
end
```

but after doing this, the relationships are not rendered in json.

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Craig Crist",
                "email": "adena_kiehn@greenfelder.com",
                "phone_number": "876.862.8760 x0096",
                "verified": true,
                "avatar": "https://robohash.org/voluptatemsintnon.png?size=300x300",
                "badge": 3,
                "catagories": "seller",
                "rating": 1,
                "created_at": "2017-06-25T10:31:39.575Z",
                "updated_at": "2017-06-25T10:31:39.575Z"
            }
```

also I was using `gem 'api-pagination'` to paginate this array, but

after the user is encapsulated inside data, the api-pagination also stops working.

How can I achieve the desired output and have it paginated ?

Comment: could you add glimpse of your controller code?

Comment: its default feature of serializers to wrap data with `data` key and add relationships

Comment: by default it renders the all user info within root node `users`. as shown in first response above.  But my requirement needs all user info wrapped inside data, as shown in second response.

Comment: please add you controller code

Comment: the first code is my index method of seller controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two of the ways to do as you wish:

```
render json: User.all, adapter: :json_api
```

or

```
# in config/am_serializer.rb
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api

# in controller
render json: User.all
```

Now response will be rendered as

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "profile",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Julia"
    }
  }
}
```

The `json_api` adapter is designed to comply with the specification defined here http://jsonapi.org/

Useful links:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md#other

---

> but that will change the response format to jsonapi. the response format of all api will be different. client app does not follow jsonapi standards

try this, it should work

```
render json: {data: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(User.all)}
```

The default adapter would be `json` not `json_api`

Comment: but that will change the response format to jsonapi. the response format of all api will be different. client app does not follow  jsonapi standards

Comment: I though you were trying to comply